# Using a single mapping table for multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have a requirement to store multiple many-to-many relationships in a singular table for use with EntityFramework.

There are many m2m relationships in this requirement, but to highlight by example, there are:

Entity
EntityGroup
Address

Each Entity can be linked to multiple Address records, each Entity can be linked to multiple EntityGroup records. I want to use a single table to manage the relationships between these objects - something like:

```
RelationshipType    LeftID    RightID
EntityGroupEntity   1         74
EntityGroupENtity   1         83
EntityAddress       74        17
```

In the above example, EntityGroup "1" contains two entities with the ID of "74" and "83", and Entity "74" has Address "17" linked to it.

I have noted there are Mapping options in the Fluent API, using MapLeft and MapRight, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell it which relationship to look for when accessing the list. Is this possible? I haven't had any luck finding the answer to my question on the net - possibly because I am not asking it correctly!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks up a relationship by a column within a table is a very poor choice in using a RDBMS.  With RDBMS you're basically throwing away what it's really good at for a *cleaver* way to create relationships between tables.

Comment: Bad idea - you'll destroy referential integrity, optimization techniques etc. to avoid having multiple tables.

Comment: While I realise this is not what is classed as "best practice", and with all due respect, I am looking for a potential solution. There is no destruction of referential integrity if the links between objects are stored correctly in the table.

Comment: @TwistedMellow how did this structure work for you? Could you please give conclusion on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one more column to the table containing multiple m2m relations, enum type, indicating whether it is the EntityGroup or the Address you are referencing to.

```
RelationshipType    LeftID    RightID  Type
EntityGroupEntity   1         74        1
EntityGroupENtity   1         83        1
EntityAddress       74        17        2
```

The rest of the creative work is up to you. Anyway, this is bad practice (but from what I understood you have no control over the requirements).